# Powershell script to deactivate the Windows users (from CSV file) in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, active-directory

Is there any powershell scripts to deactivate the Windows users (from CSV file) in Windows Server 2003? Those Windows users are local user accounts (Not AD Accounts). In fact, I found a lot of such scripts for AD. Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you. Please change the placeholders according to your requirement:

```
$EnableUser = 512 
$DisableUser = 2 
$PasswordNotExpire = 65536 # password never expires
$PasswordCantChange = 64  # passwords cannot be changed
$users = Import-Csv "path\Users_to_disable.csv" # I believe you have only single column else you have to pick the column 
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME

Foreach($user in $users){ $user = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$user"
$user.userflags = $DisableUser+$PasswordNotExpire+$PasswordCantChange
#$user.Userflags = $EnableUser+$PasswordNotExpire+$PasswordCantChange
$user.setinfo()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ranadip! Let me try that out.

Comment: @KyawThurein :  Accept the answer if it helps you.

Comment: +1 @Ranadip. Adding $user = $user.{csv_column_name} before [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$user" solves the problem! Thanks

Comment: Great. happy to guide you :)